# What steps should I take to build and run .net core Web API application in 32-bit environment/runtime?

Tags: iis, .net-core, x86, msbuild, 32-bit

We developed an a .NET Core Web API application using the following technologies:

-NET Core (3.1)

-Visual Studio 2019

Unfortunately, we have to deploy said application to the following environment:

-32-bit Environment

-Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Service Pack 1)

-IIS Version 7.5

-8 GB RAM

Therefore, within my Visual Studio 2019, I brought up the application, and took the following steps:

**Force x86 in VS go to the Properties > Build and change Platform target from Any CPU to x86**

Created a  Directory.Build.targets in the the .NET Core application's Project root directory:

> ```
> <Project>
>
>       <PropertyGroup
>
>       Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' and
>
>                  '$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x86' and
>
>                  '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' and
>
>                  '$(SelfContained)' != 'true'"
>
>                   >
>
>        <RunCommand>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
>
>       </PropertyGroup>
>
> < /Project >
> ```

From Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.4.6, I navigated to the .NET Core application's Project root directory.

I ran:

>
>

> ```
> dotnet clean
> ...........................
> .............
>
> dotnet build
>
>
> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5):
> error MSB4216: Could not run the "ResolveComReference" task because
> MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4"
> and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime
> and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the
> required executable "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\MSBuild.exe"
> exists and can be run.
> [D:\ blah blah.csproj]
>     6 Warning(s)
>     1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:04.63'
> ```

Could someone please tell me how I can build and run this application in a 32-bit environment?

Comment: Are you sure you've installed the .net Core 3.1 x86 SDK on the machine you're running dotnet build on? (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)

Comment: Have you tried downloading a x86 SDK and using that (not the x64 SDK) to build and publish the web app?

Answer (score 1):

> What steps should I take to build and run .net core Web API
>   application in 32-bit environment/runtime?

It is quite strange. **First**, just as **akseli** and **omajid** said, try to install [Net Core 3.1 x86 sdk version](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

Then, try the following steps:

**Steps**

**1)** change build platform target to `x86` in 32-bit environment.

**2)** when you migrate the project into 32-bit environment, please delete `.vs` hidden folder which exists under the solution folder, `bin`, `obj` folder.

**3)** open [Developer Command Prompt for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) in **32-bit** environment(it call the `msbuild.exe` under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe`) to build your project.

**4)** try to use `msbuild` rather than `dotnet build` since MSBuild is more powerful and has a wider range of compilations.

```
msbuild xxx.csproj -t:build

msbuild xxx.csproj -t:clean
```

**4)** or add these node in your `xxx.csproj` file then build your project

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Core'">
  <GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>CurrentArchitecture</GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>
  <GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>CurrentRuntime</GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Any feedback will be expected.

Answer (score 1):

@akseli @omajid @perry-qian-msft @yongqing-yu **Sorry, this failed to work, we had to move away from using .NET Core technology( and had to migrate over to .NET Framework 4.7.2) because it would work properly for a little while, and then give us 500 error, and then later some 401 error.**  I think it has something to do with the configuration because we are using:

-NET Core (3.1)

-In-Process within IIS Server

therefore, Within the standalone IIS Server, we should Not have to run  the .NET Core (3.1) application within it's own application pool as "Not Managed Code" because it's all In-Process and .NET Core (3.1) can run on IIS.  In any case, we do Not have time to resolve this problem so we migrate over to .NET Framework 4.7.2

@akseli @omajid @perry-qian-msft @yongqing-yu All Thank you for all your responses.
My Team Tech Lead found the solution by specifying the .NET Core Web API Application's Build Settings to "Any CPU" Within Visual Studio 2019. ( Within Visual Studio 2019, Right-click on .NET Core Web API Application, and then choose properties from the drop-down context menu, and then when the window pane shows up on, you select the Build Tab. )
[image]

Also, on the IIS Server, my Team Tech Lead ensured that that deployed .NET Core Web API Application's Application pool had the following settings( important to keep in mind that it is "Not Managed Code": 
[image]